# Embedding video players play button plays all video players at once

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I'm trying to embed videos in my website with custom video players and when I embed more than one video when I press the play button on any of the videos it plays all of the videos at once instead of just the one I click play on. The code items are down below:

goto the jsfiddle below and run the code then press play on a video and you'll see it plays both videos at once instead of the one you click.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.scss">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--Video 1-->
        <section id="wrapper">
            <div class="videoContainer">
                <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_poster.jpg" width="380" >
                    <source src="http://html-testing.github.io/2/videos/mikethefrog.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
                </video>
                <div class="caption">Video1</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <div class="btmControl">
                        <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"><span class="icon-play"></span></div>
                        <div class="progress-bar">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <span class="bufferBar"></span>
                                <span class="timeBar"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="volume" title="Set volume">
                        <span class="volumeBar"></span>
                        </div>-->
                        <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"><span class="icon-sound"></span></div>
                        <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"><span class="icon-fullscreen"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <!--Video 2-->
        <section id="wrapper">
            <div class="videoContainer">

                <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_poster.jpg" width="380" >
                    <source src="http://html-testing.github.io/2/videos/mikethefrog.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
                </video>
                <div class="caption">Video2</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <div class="btmControl">
                        <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"><span class="icon-play"></span></div>
                        <div class="progress-bar">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <span class="bufferBar"></span>
                                <span class="timeBar"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="volume" title="Set volume">
                        <span class="volumeBar"></span>
                        </div>-->
                        <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"><span class="icon-sound"></span></div>
                        <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"><span class="icon-fullscreen"></span></div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1f323e;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse cover at 80% 0%, #426168 0%, rgba(49, 67, 74, 0.1) 100%), radial-gradient(ellipse cover at 20% 100%, #080d11 0%, #243a43 100%);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

video {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

/* video container */
.videoContainer {
  width: 380px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin: 50px auto 0;
}

.videoContainer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  z-index: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* video caption css */
.caption {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/*** VIDEO CONTROLS CSS ***/
/* control holder */
.control {
  color: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 360px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}

/* control bottom part */
.btmControl {
  clear: both;
}

.control .btnPlay {
  float: left;
  width: 34px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.control .icon-play {
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_sprite.png) no-repeat -11px 0;
  width: 6px;
  height: 9px;
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 0 0 8px;
}

.control .icon-pause {
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_sprite.png) no-repeat -34px -1px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  display: block;
  margin: 4px 0 0 8px;
}

.control .selected {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.control .sound {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.control .icon-sound {
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_sprite.png) no-repeat -19px 0;
  width: 13px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.control .muted .icon-sound {
  width: 7px !important;
}

.control .btnFS {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  float: left;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.control .icon-fullscreen {
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/6035/vp_sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin: 8px 0 0 9px;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
/* Progress bar */
.progress-bar {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-left: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  float: left;
}

.progress {
  width: 240px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* fallback */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), inset 0 1px 1px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.progress span {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.timeBar {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6bcce2 0%, #1da3d0 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(107, 204, 226, 0.5);
}

.bufferBar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/*
JS Modified from a tutorial found here: 
http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5...ls-with-jquery/
I really wanted to learn how to skin html5 video.
*/
$(document).ready(function(){
    //INITIALIZE
    var video = $('#myVideo');

    //remove default control when JS loaded
    video[0].removeAttribute("controls");
    $('.control').fadeIn(500);
    $('.caption').fadeIn(500);

    //before everything get started
    video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {

        //set video properties
        $('.current').text(timeFormat(0));
        $('.duration').text(timeFormat(video[0].duration));
        updateVolume(0, 0.7);

        //start to get video buffering data 
        setTimeout(startBuffer, 150);

        //bind video events
        $('.videoContainer')
        .hover(function() {
            $('.control').stop().fadeIn();
            $('.caption').stop().fadeIn();
        }, function() {
            if(!volumeDrag && !timeDrag){
                $('.control').stop().fadeOut();
                $('.caption').stop().fadeOut();
            }
        })
        .on('click', function() {
            $('.btnPlay').find('.icon-play').addClass('icon-pause').removeClass('icon-play');
            $(this).unbind('click');
            video[0].play();
        });
    });

    //display video buffering bar
    var startBuffer = function() {
        var currentBuffer = video[0].buffered.end(0);
        var maxduration = video[0].duration;
        var perc = 100 * currentBuffer / maxduration;
        $('.bufferBar').css('width',perc+'%');

        if(currentBuffer < maxduration) {
            setTimeout(startBuffer, 500);
        }
    };  

    //display current video play time
    video.on('timeupdate', function() {
        var currentPos = video[0].currentTime;
        var maxduration = video[0].duration;
        var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
        $('.timeBar').css('width',perc+'%');    
        $('.current').text(timeFormat(currentPos)); 
    });

    //CONTROLS EVENTS
    //video screen and play button clicked
    video.on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
    $('.btnPlay').on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
    var playpause = function() {
        if(video[0].paused || video[0].ended) {
            $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
            $('.btnPlay').find('.icon-play').addClass('icon-pause').removeClass('icon-play');
            video[0].play();
        } else {
            $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
            $('.btnPlay').find('.icon-pause').removeClass('icon-pause').addClass('icon-play');
            video[0].pause();
        }
    };


    //fullscreen button clicked
    $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
        if($.isFunction(video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen)) {
            video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
        }   
        else if ($.isFunction(video[0].mozRequestFullScreen)) {
            video[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else {
            alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
        }
    });

    //sound button clicked
    $('.sound').click(function() {
        video[0].muted = !video[0].muted;
        $(this).toggleClass('muted');
        if(video[0].muted) {
            $('.volumeBar').css('width',0);
        } else {
            $('.volumeBar').css('width', video[0].volume*100+'%');
        }
    });

    //VIDEO EVENTS
    //video canplay event
    video.on('canplay', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
    });

    //video canplaythrough event
    //solve Chrome cache issue
    var completeloaded = false;
    video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
        completeloaded = true;
    });

    //video ended event
    video.on('ended', function() {
        $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
        video[0].pause();
    });

    //video seeking event
    video.on('seeking', function() {
        //if video fully loaded, ignore loading screen
        if(!completeloaded) { 
            $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
        }   
    });

    //video seeked event
    video.on('seeked', function() { });

    //video waiting for more data event
    video.on('waiting', function() {
        $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    });

    //VIDEO PROGRESS BAR
    //when video timebar clicked
    var timeDrag = false;   /* check for drag event */
    $('.progress').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        timeDrag = true;
        updatebar(e.pageX);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        if(timeDrag) {
            timeDrag = false;
            updatebar(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if(timeDrag) {
            updatebar(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    var updatebar = function(x) {
        var progress = $('.progress');

        //calculate drag position
        //and update video currenttime
        //as well as progress bar
        var maxduration = video[0].duration;
        var position = x - progress.offset().left;
        var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
        if(percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if(percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }
        $('.timeBar').css('width',percentage+'%');  
        video[0].currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
    };

    //VOLUME BAR
    //volume bar event
    var volumeDrag = false;
    $('.volume').on('mousedown', function(e) {
        volumeDrag = true;
        video[0].muted = false;
        $('.sound').removeClass('muted');
        updateVolume(e.pageX);
    });
    $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        if(volumeDrag) {
            volumeDrag = false;
            updateVolume(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        if(volumeDrag) {
            updateVolume(e.pageX);
        }
    });
    var updateVolume = function(x, vol) {
        var volume = $('.volume');
        var percentage;
        //if only volume have specificed
        //then direct update volume
        if(vol) {
            percentage = vol * 100;
        } else {
            var position = x - volume.offset().left;
            percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
        }

        if(percentage > 100) {
            percentage = 100;
        }
        if(percentage < 0) {
            percentage = 0;
        }

        //update volume bar and video volume
        $('.volumeBar').css('width',percentage+'%');    
        video[0].volume = percentage / 100;

        //change sound icon based on volume
        if(video[0].volume === 0){
            $('.sound').removeClass('sound2').addClass('muted');
        }
        else if(video[0].volume > 0.5){
            $('.sound').removeClass('muted').addClass('sound2');
        } else {
            $('.sound').removeClass('muted').removeClass('sound2');
        }

    };

    //Time format converter - 00:00
    var timeFormat = function(seconds){
        var m = Math.floor(seconds/60)<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds/60) : Math.floor(seconds/60);
        var s = Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)) : Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
        return m+":"+s;
    };
});
```

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/BannerBomb/zr67w0y0/2/) for JS Fiddle.

Comment: since you're the one asking for help, it's reasonable that you create the jsbin

Comment: Seriously?  This is the *smallest* amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem?  You need *all* if that CSS, including a custom font-face?

Comment: BannerBomb: as a new user, if you receive valuable edits from experienced users, please do not roll back without contacting those editors (cc @cimmanon). Please also do not add ASAP begging to your posts, nor ask for readers to send you an email - these are also considered rude, since they are not respectful of volunteers' valuable time. I will roll this back, and if I see you participating in an edit war again, you will get a moderator flag.

Comment: +hallfer ok I understand but i only rolled it back because when they edited it they took out some of  my CSS code which is supposed to have that @import "compass/css3" at the top because its a SCSS code with Compass otherwise the design wont work like its supposed to. I'm just saying because i was wandering why they changed it from SCSS to CSS and took out the Compass part?

Comment: I see your point, though there is already quite a lot of material to wade through already, and this appears to be a JavaScript question, not a CSS/SASS question. However, if you can prepare a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) then you can set that all up yourself. The fiddle will create a link for you, which you can put at the bottom of your post. That will help you demonstrate the problem easily.

Comment: @halfer is it ok if I use jsbin.com thats the one I use the most this one creates a link to or does it have to be jsfiddle because jsfiddle blocked on my computer its not mine its my schools they just let us use them? and when do this am i allowed to edit it as and take out the code snippets? and put the link in the post instead

Comment: Yes you can use jsbin, but no, please do _not_ take out the code snippets here. If we cannot understand your question without going to an external link, it is likely to get closed by the community. We tend to expect external links to die off in due course, and we want questions to survive after that.

Comment: @halfer ok is that edit good enough?

Comment: Looks fine to me! Thanks for the edits.

Comment: @BannerBomb None of your CSS was removed.  I converted the Sass to CSS because the problem has absolutely nothing to do with Sass whatsoever.  Do not use tags/code unless they are actually related to the problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple ID's on one page. Change the video id's to classes. That is probably why you aren't getting the results you want.

After that, on click you can do:

```
$('.myVideo').each(function(){
    this.play();
});
```

or

```
$('video').each(function(){
    this.play();
});
```

### EDIT

So upon re-reading the question I finally understand what you need to do. Your event selectors and everything should still be good.

1- change:

```
var video = $('#myVideo');
to
var video = $('.myVideo');
```

2- Pass the `$(this).parents(.videoContainer)` variable to your `playpause()` function. This will enable you to access the video container that is being clicked.

You can also consolidate your event function calls to one line:

```
$(document).on('click', 'video, .btnPlay', function(){
    playPause($(this).parents('.videoContainer'));
});

var playPause = function($that){
    var $playBtn = $that.find('.btnPlay');
    var video = $that.find('video').get(0);

    //video.pause() and video.play() is what you will you use to play/pause
    //put your conditional statements and stuff here
}
```

Comment: im sorry im not real good with JavaScript much so where would I out the code u gave me after i changed the ids to classes? i know it goes in the JavaScript section but where and do i need to change or delete anything in the javascript part?

Comment: @BannerBomb take a look

Comment: im sorry i really am i understand what to do with the renaming part but when you on step 2 i dont understand where to put them so can you please edit the JS part of the code so and post your part then I can compare what u did to what mine is so I know what to do in the future? im sorry if im asking for alot or if i sound stupid but im not really a JS person im more of a HTML and PHP